# Код, сгенерированный с помощью protoc не компилится

Tags: c++, google-protobuf, grpc

Я сгенерировал код с помощью protoc, но он не компилится, все зависимости установлены правильно, но вылетают какие то глупые компайл тайм ошибки, подчеркиваемые ide.
К примеру

> ‘AuxiliaryParseTableField’ in namespace ‘google::protobuf::internal’
> does not name a type; did you mean ‘AuxillaryParseTableField’?    48 |
> static const
> ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::AuxiliaryParseTableField aux[]
>
> expected initializer before ‘:’ token    73 | class AddRequest
> PROTOBUF_FINAL :
> |                                 ^

И так далее.
cmake файл взят из официальной документации, но, как мне кажется, дело не в нем

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(grpc_test1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        gRPC
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc
        GIT_TAG        v1.28.0
)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gRPC)


add_executable(grpc_test1 main.cpp test.pb.cc test.pb.h test.grpc.pb.cc test.grpc.pb.h)
target_link_libraries(grpc_test1 grpc++)
```

Comment: все у Вас компилится. Другое дело, что оно не линкуется. похоже, протобаф не добавлен в список библиотек.

Comment: @KoVadim, а как это сделать?? я пробовал финд пэкэдж, но мне пишет что такой либы  нет в системе, в таком случае, как ее скачать? Я пробовал через репозиторий ubuntu libgrpc-dev. Всю установку я производил по инструкции из офф документации, пример оттуда тоже скомпилился и работает.

Comment: я не большой специалист в впиливании cmake (скорее, я любитель его выпилить:)) но похоже последнюю строку нужно поправить на такую `target_link_libraries(grpc_test1libprotobuf grpc++)`

Comment: @KoVadim, не помогло =((

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь добавить protobuf через find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) мне выдает ошибку Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR). Но вообще, как я понял(может я понял не правильно) данный cmake код сам должен все подтягивать.

Comment: а протобаф установлен?

Comment: @KoVadim, я смог добавить протобаф. Вообще, по моему, пишет что ошибки синтаксические.

Comment: Судя по всему, проблема правда в protobuf, потому что имена, которые не видит программой оттуда, но не понятно почему он их не видит, я добавил в cmake файл 
find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED ) и target_link_libraries(grpc_test1 libprotobuf grpc++)

Comment: пересмотрел сейчас ещё раз. да, похоже на ошибку компиляции. А include добавили необходимые для протобаф? ` find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )` - это просто "найди библиотеку и выставь определенные переменные, не более. А добавлять в остальные места нужно уже самому.

Comment: @KoVadim, просто по идее, инклуды должен protoc генерировать

Comment: Я сомневаюсь. Посмотрите сюда https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindProtobuf.html